# symfony 1.4: doctrine:build-sql issue

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I made the mistake of defining in my schema a column named `desc` which is a reserved keyword. I quickly realized my mistake and changed my schema, revising my schema column name to `description`.

Now, when I run `doctrine:build --all` or `doctrine:build-sql` it is still generating sql based on my past mistake.

I verify this, because it is still producing the sql statement with `desc` in the sentence, which has been since removed. I've cleared my cache, removed the original sql file, and cleared my logs.

How in the world is `doctrine:build-sql` generating a mistake that is completely deleted and removed? How can I correct this problem?

Obviously, until I can fix it, `doctrine:build` is broken.

**EDIT:**

Here's my original schema:

```
ReasonCode:
  columns:
    id:          { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
    desc: { type: string }

RejectionCode:
  columns:
    id:          { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
    desc: { type: string }

ConsiderationCode:
  columns:
    id:          { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
    desc: { type: string }
```

and here's my revised schema:

```
ReasonCode:
  columns:
    id:          { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
    name: { type: string }

RejectionCode:
  columns:
    id:          { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
    name: { type: string }

ConsiderationCode:
  columns:
    id:          { type: integer, primary: true, notnull: true, autoincrement: true, unique: true }
    name: { type: string }
```

here's the generated sql schema being generated every time:

```
CREATE TABLE consideration_code (id BIGINT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT, desc TEXT, name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE reason_code (id BIGINT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT, desc TEXT, name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
CREATE TABLE rejection_code (id BIGINT UNIQUE AUTO_INCREMENT, desc TEXT, name TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doctrine:build-sql` generate SQL based on the generated model (the php classes). You need to regenerate the model first using `doctrine:build-model`.

Don't you have an other `desc` field in your `schema.yml` ? Have you tried to empty the folders `cache` ? Could you paste your `schema.yml` ?

Is the `desc` field still in your generated model (the php file) ?

**edit:**

One other radical solution:

1. empty your `schema.yml`
2. run `doctrine:clean-model-files` to clean all old model
3. put your new `schema.yml` (the corrected one)
4. re-run `doctrine:build --all`

Comment: I've tried it both ways: doctrine:build-model and then doctrine:build-sql, and then doctrine:build --all, which does everything in correct order.  Both ways still results in generated sql with the old error.  My php generated models also contain the error, with a "desc" field in addition to the revised column; i.e. I have two columns in my php model whereas in my schema I only have one column.  I've also tried to clean my models with doctrine:clean-model-files, which didn't find anything to clean.  I'll post my schema in my original question, but it's very simple.

Comment: I'll give it a try... stand by.

Comment: I feel so stupid.  Thanks to your suggestion, it led me to the answer. When I emptied the original schema, and then tried to clean the model files, the result said "Could not find any files that need to be removed".  The solution after that become obvious: I was copying and renaming my old schema file, as backup, and placing it in the same config/doctrine folder.  Didn't realize that everything placed in that folder would attempt to be run.  I removed the old files to a different directory and re-run build commands.  Problem solved. Thanks, man.